# How to resolve dependency?

Tags: angular

I have a class:

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchByAddressParcel implements SearchAddress {
    private _response;

    get response() {
        return this._response;
    }

    set response(value) {
        this._response = value;
    }

    constructor(private CloudService: CloudEsService, private searchConfig: SearchConfig) {}

    search(): Observable<any> {
        return this.CloudService.search(this.searchConfig.parameters);
    }
}
```

This class has injection `private CloudService: CloudEsService, private searchConfig: SearchConfig`.

I resolve this class in provider:

```
 providers: [
        SearchByAddressParcel,
        { provide: SearchByAddressParcel, useClass: SearchConfig },
    ],
```

But how to resolve `SearchConfig` and pass it as parameter for `SearchByAddressParcel`?

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchConfig {
    constructor(public config: SearchParameters) {

   }
}
```

I have tried this:

```
providers: [
    SearchByAddressParcel,
    SearchConfig,
    { provide: SearchConfig, useValue: { layers: [37], types: [4, 5, 6], helpSearch: false, searchText: '', searchType: 2 } },
    { provide: SearchByAddressParcel, useClass: SearchConfig },
],
```

Then I have tried this:

```
export const SEARCH_PARAMETERS = new InjectionToken<SearchParameters>('SEARCH_PARAMETERS');

@Injectable()
export class SearchConfig {
    private layers: number[];
    private types: number[];
    private searchType: number;
    private _searchText: string;

    constructor(@Inject(SEARCH_PARAMETERS) config: SearchParameters) {
}
```

**Provider:**

```
  providers: [
        SearchConfig,
        SearchByAddressParcel,
        { provide: SEARCH_PARAMETERS, useValue: { layers: [37], types: [4, 5, 6], helpSearch: false, searchText: '', searchType: 2 } },
        { provide: SearchByAddressParcel, useClass: SearchConfig },
    ],
```

Problem is provider can not resolve `CloudEsService` for  `SearchByAddressParcel`.

Comment: why are you trying to provide `SearchConfig` under the same injection token as `SearchByAddressParcel`? just make it a separate injection token

Comment: Why are you listing the CloudEsService service in your providers array? If you want to inject it, it has to be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of providers is partially wrong: you have multiple registrations for the same token, and `useClass` is not to be used like that.

First, you should try to follow Angular's naming conventions and name your services with the `Service` suffix (probably, your class`SearchByAddressParcel` should become an `AddressSearchService` or something like that).

Second: your `SearchByAddressParcel` seems to be a class to be used as a single instance. Since Angular v5 (if I remember correctly) you can just use the `{providedIn: 'root'}` shortcut: you don't need an entry in `providers`.

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SearchByAddressParcel implements SearchAddress {
    private _response;

    get response() {
        return this._response;
    }

    set response(value) {
        this._response = value;
    }

    constructor(private CloudService: CloudEsService, private searchConfig: SearchConfig) {}

    search(): Observable<any> {
        return this.CloudService.search(this.searchConfig.parameters);
    }
}
```

What `providedIn` does is very much like inserting an automatic registration in the base AppModule of your application. The provider is exactly like: `{ provide: SearchByAddressParcel, useClass: SearchByAddressParcel }`.

Now, to allow Angular to build an instance of `SearchByAddressParcel` you need to tell him how to resolve `CloudEsService` (I assume it's another `providedIn: 'root'`) and `SearchConfig`.

Because of the latter, we need just ONE provider in our AppModule, the one for `SearchConfig`.

If `SearchConfig` it's a compile time constant, or if you can read it from the page, you can leverage `useValue`:

```js
// in app.Module.ts
const config = new SearchConfig(... your settings ...);

@NgModule({
  // ...
  providers: [
    { provide: SearchConfig, useValue: config }
  ]
})
// ...
```

If it's not, you can use a factory method. Some examples you can find in the [Dependency Injection Guide](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection), in the official Angular docs, especially https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#factory-providers.

Try to take the time to read the whole thing: it's worth gold.